# loved? or beloved? (what is the difference?)

Tags: word-usage

I don't know the exact meaning of 'beloved'.
Could you tell me the meaning of 'beloved'?
please, tell me the exact difference of the words.

Comment: Beloved is adjective or noun while loved is past participle. See:http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beloved_1

Comment: *loved* is also an adjective! @Cardinal

Comment: *Be-* is a older English prefix which is basically an intensifier: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/be-

Answer (score 3):

No difference if you talk about both being adjectives.

You can say...

> *'....when a **loved** pet dies....'*

**However,** you find *'beloved'* more frequently used than *'loved'* when you are using it as an adjective.

So, to answer this, if you are using the word as an *adjective*, prefer which is more common and understandable - **beloved**.

Answer (score 0):

While anyone can be loved, I believe that beloved is used to define a greater love by many others.  It means that object of the affection is more loved than most and that many people know of this person and they are loved above the norm.

Comment: You could support your answer by referencing a reputable resource, such as a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Loved is something used to express for past situation.
eg : I loved my Exgirlfriend so much

beloved is used to denote somethin you love extremely.your favorite

eg: I am wating here for my beloved daughter .

Comment: Not so.  Loved can describe something you currently love, not just in the past.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes... *she's the most loved one in the family*

Comment: *beloved* is also used to show someone who died; e.g.: _he was the beloved of many_.